# How to mock a memoized React component with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, memoization

I want to mock a React component that has been memoized. I'm using React 18.2 and Jest 29.7 with Typescript, in case that matters. I've tried several things but can't seem to find a way that works.

Here's a minimal example of where I started from:

```tsx
// Foo.tsx
import Bar from "./Bar";

export default function Foo() {
  return <Bar />;
}
```

```tsx
// Bar.tsx
import { memo } from "react";

function Bar() {
  return <div>original</div>;
}

export default memo(Bar);
```

```tsx
//Foo.test.tsx
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Foo from "./Foo";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

const barModule = require("./Bar");

describe("Foo", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(barModule, "default")
      .mockImplementation(() => <div>mocked</div>);
  });

  it("should mock Bar", () => {
    render(<Foo />);

    expect(screen.queryByText("mocked")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

When Bar isn't memoized, the test succeeds. But with the call to memo, I get this error message:

```
Cannot spy on the `default` property because it is not a function; object given instead.
```

The internet quickly told me that I should export the non-memoized component and mock that one instead. So I did (Foo.tsx is unchanged):

```tsx
// Bar.tsx
import { memo } from "react";

export function Bar_() {
  return <div>original</div>;
}

export default memo(Bar_);
```

```tsx
//Foo.test.tsx
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Foo from "./Foo";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

const barModule = require("./Bar");

describe("Foo", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(barModule, "Bar_")
      .mockImplementation(() => <div>mocked</div>);
  });

  it("should mock Bar", () => {
    render(<Foo />);

    expect(screen.queryByText("mocked")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This fails because the mock isn't applied for some reason. The original Bar_ implementation is used.

The internet also suggested mocking the whole module, so I tried this (the other two files unchanged):

```tsx
//Foo.test.tsx
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Foo from "./Foo";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("Foo", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock("./Bar", () => {
      const originalModule = jest.requireActual("./Bar");
      return {
        ...originalModule,
        Bar_: () => <div>Baba</div>,
      };
    });
  });

  it("should mock Bar", () => {
    render(<Foo />);

    screen.debug();
    expect(screen.queryByText("mocked")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This fails because of this error:

```
The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
Invalid variable access: _jsxFileName
```

I know that you can usually avoid this error by renaming the variable to something starting with “mock”. But what is this _jsxFileName?

I actually figured this out while typing this. I'll keep this step anyway in case someone is also stuck at this point. So I fixed this by extracting the mocked component to a variable whose name starts with “Mock”. Now I have this:

```tsx
//Foo.test.tsx
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import Foo from "./Foo";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("Foo", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const MockBar_ = () => <div>Baba</div>;

    jest.mock("./Bar", () => {
      const originalModule = jest.requireActual("./Bar");
      return {
        ...originalModule,
        Bar_: MockBar_,
      };
    });
  });

  it("should mock Bar", () => {
    render(<Foo />);

    screen.debug();
    expect(screen.queryByText("mocked")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This fails again because the mock isn't applied, but the original Bar_ component is used.

So how do you actually do this? :-D

Comment: Why does it matter whether or not the component is memoized, if you're mocking it out? `Foo` doesn't care whether or not `Bar` is memoized, why would its tests? Note you need `jest.mock` calls to be at the top level of the module to be hoisted above the actual imports.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, apparently, memoizing Bar makes it an object instead of a function such that Jest cannot mock it. At least that's what the error message sounds like to me: “Cannot spy on the `default` property because it is not a function; object given instead.”

As for the hoisting: Good point. I'll try putting the mock calls at top level.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I tried to put the mock (and the spyOn) calls at top level. Made no difference. Could you give a concrete example how you think this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jest.replaceProperty(object, propertyKey, value)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value) to replace `object[propertyKey]` with a `value`.

E.g.

`Bar.tsx`:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

function Bar() {
  return <div>original</div>;
}

export default memo(Bar);
```

`Foo.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Bar from './Bar';

export default function Foo() {
  return <Bar />;
}
```

`Foo.test.tsx`:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import Foo from './Foo';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

const barModule = require('./Bar');

describe('Foo', () => {
  it('should mock Bar', () => {
    jest.replaceProperty(barModule, 'default', () => <div>mocked</div>);
    render(<Foo />);
    expect(screen.queryByText('mocked')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77770830/Foo.test.tsx
  Foo
    √ should mock Bar (17 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.11 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package version:

```json
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```